# Question about residual diagnostic tests in time series

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, residuals, diagnostic

I was reading a chapter from [this book](https://otexts.com/fpp3/diagnostics.html#fn3) on residual diagnostics for time series data. The book presents Box Pierce and Ljung Box test statistics $Q = T\sum_{k=1}^lr_k^2$ and $Q^*=T(T+2)\sum_{k=1}^l(T-k)^{-1}r_k^2$ (where $r_k$ is autocorrelation for lag $k$) and that if the residuals are white noise $Q$ and $Q^*$ are $\chi^2$ distributed.

My question may be more related to hypothesis testing in general. If the residuals are not white noise, then I assume it's possible that $Q$ and $Q^*$ are not $\chi^2$ distributed. In this case, if $Q$ / $Q^*$ happen to exceed some threshold value based on $\chi^2$ distribution, then we would correctly reject the null hypothesis even though $Q$ / $Q^*$ and the threshold references two different distributions. However, if that is not the case, we would not accept the null hypothesis. Is this logic correct?